# Reshape 3d matrix in z direction

Tags: matlab

we have a = [1 2; 3 4]; and b = [5 6;7 8]; and z = cat(3,a,b). I want to vectorize the 3d matrix so the reresult would be c = [1  5; 2 6; 3 7; 4 8 ]? I know it is related to `reshape` but I can not find the way:)

Thanks.

Comment: After a good lunch, having a = z(:,:,1), b = z(:,:,2) => c = [a(:) b(:)]. More naive than the following answers.

Comment: not quite, since you need to call `permute` on `z` first..

Comment: What do you mean? It is not correct?

Comment: `c` will be `[1 5;3 7;2 6;4 8]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to go via z:

```
c = reshape(permute(z,[2 1 3]),[],2)
```

Otherwise,

```
c = [reshape(a',[],1),reshape(b',[],1)];
```

Comment: Those two aren't the same - only the second provides the right answer. Ah. You've added the permute now ;)

Comment: @Edric: I've noticed and fixed it in the meantime. Testing helps. Thanks for the heads-up, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

```
reshape(permute(z,[2 1 3]), 4, 2)
```

Comment: @Jonas Maybe not quite first time.